# Is there any way to recover a sheet in One Drive (that is in xlsx format) to local .ODS format?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I followed this tutorial which did not work but I can only recover in xlsx :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Is there any way to recover it directly in .ODS or convert the recovered file in .ODS with Microsoft functions or others?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

MS Graph has a [file conversion API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content-format?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) but it does not support XLSX to ODS.